# Getting 401 Unauthorized for every Rest Api Call despite having valid token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, java-17, spring-boot-starter-security

I am using spring security and oauth2 to make my rest api secure. I can get the access token successfully. But I am getting 401 Unauthorized for every Rest Api Call despite having valid token.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My tech stack is:

- SpringBoot 3
- SpringBootSecurity3
- Java17

My pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Bean 
        @Order(1)
        public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
                throws Exception {
            OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
            http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
            http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(null)
                    .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                        new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                        new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    )
                )
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                    .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

            return http.build();
        }

        @Bean
        @Order(2)  
        public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .securityMatcher("/bookshell/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/v3/api-docs", "/v3/api-docs/**","/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/ui","/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
            return http.build();
        }

        @Bean 
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
                            
            UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername("user")
                    .password("password")
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();

            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
        }

        @Bean 
        public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
            RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .clientId("BookShellClient")
                    .clientSecret(passwordEncoder().encode("secret"))
                    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                    .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8081/login/oauth2/code/BookShellClient")
                    .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8081/")
                    .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8081/authorized")
                    .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                    .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                    .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                    .build();

            return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
        }

        @Bean 
        public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
            KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
            RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                    .privateKey(privateKey)
                    .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .build();
            JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
            return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
        }

        private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() { 
            KeyPair keyPair;
            try {
                KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
                keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
            }
            return keyPair;
        }

        @Bean 
        public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
            return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
        }

        @Bean 
        public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
            return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

}
```

Comment: Your `apiFilterChain` is not a resource server security filter-chain (request authorization with `Bearer` access token is for OAuth2 resource servers). Read this: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials